# How to run migrations in a forked django app?

Tags: django, migration, fork, package

I know it sounds like a dumb question and I myself felt terribly bad when I faced this unforgivable lack of knowledge about a framework that I use basically every day...but so it is!

I had the necessity of forking a django package to add some fields to some of its models. Everything fine, I forked the project on github, cloned locally and then realized that: any django package does not include a common django setup so how am I supposed to run the migrations I need in order to complete my changes and push back to the repo the new version of the app?

I thought of course of starting another django project and cloning the fork as an app but doesn't that feel a bit over the top for a process like this? What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: I think you have no choice. You must start a django project and add your app in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Or write the migrations manually.

Comment: if you're using it in your `INSTALLED_APPS` it should recognize the migration. I'm guessing that is not the case with your situation. What package are you forking?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS is not there since a package is django-agnostic (so it ships without settings.py). That is the source of my problem!

Comment: If INSTALLED_APPS isn't there, you'll have to create the project and add it into the settings. But the, becuase it's an app, the exact setup shouldn't matter, so you can just use the out of the box sqlite setup and run the migrations.

Comment: I could be misunderstanding the issue...but do you need migrations at all? If it's only an app (with no associated project or database), why do you need to migrate anything?

Comment: Because the purpose of the fork is to add a few fields to some models. I then need to generate the migration files for these changes so I can push back a complete version of the app and I can put it among the requirements in my projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app ships without any project environment, but in development you **need** a project environment. Be it for making migrations, running tests, running the server or running checks.

Creating a django project is the way to go. Unless you decide to write migrations yourself and discard tests.

I guess django apps repositories to not provide a django project environment because it's up to the developer to configure it.

Comment: makes sense indeed. Somehow the whole process seemed convoluted to me. Best answer until (and if) someone can come up with a better idea :)